# ToolTip displays in wrong place when Combobox opens in upward direction

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I have a Combobox opening in upward direction and on draw mode I have added a tool tip.

While opening downwards, tool tip displays in perfect location. But while opening upwards, tool tip displays at 10-15 items below.

```
if (e.Index < 0)
{ 
    return;
}

string text = cmbVariablesExp2.GetItemText(cmbVariablesExp2.Items[e.Index]);
e.DrawBackground();

using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
{ 
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, br, e.Bounds); 
}

if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected 
         && cmbVariablesExp2Dropdowned)
{ 
    toolTip1.Show(text, cmbVariablesExp2, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom); 
}
e.DrawFocusRectangle();
```

Comment: More code is required, the entire method, not just code inside the method body.

Comment: toolTip1.Show(text, cmbVariablesExp2, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom);   This is only a line where i need to change but I am not getting it

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix to your question is

```
if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected 
   && dropdownward)
{ 
    toolTip1.Show(text, cmbVariablesExp2, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom); 
}
else if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected 
     && dropupward)
{
    toolTip1.Show(text, cmbVariablesExp2, e.Bounds.Right, 
        e.Bounds.Bottom -cmbVariablesExp2.DropDownHeight); 
}
```

But I don't know how to determine the dropdown direction is upward or downward.